# rvm and octopress cannot generate gists and pictures under mac

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, octopress

Since I installed [octopress](http://octopress.org) I can not run `rake generate` for posts that include pictures, code or other media. I get all kind of errors.

I'm using rvm's `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]` under Mountain Lion. As a package manager I use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org). Is there anything I need to install or that I can do to fix this? It's getting really annoying... :-(

Thanks in advance, right bellow [you can see the log here](http://d.pr/n/Z0Rw). I wasn't able to post it on stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: what compiler did you use to compile ruby? you can check this with: `grep CC /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/config`

Comment: ➜  ~  grep CC .rvm//rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/config
CCDLFLAGS="-fno-common"
GCC="yes"
CC="clang"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you used `clang` for compiling ruby, this is not fully supported. There is at least one known bug with Fibers, and others problems might happen depending on `clang` version.

Ruby should be compiled with GNU GCC - you can find instructions how to get it by reading output of:

```
rvm requirements
```

There is also slightly chance this could be OpenSSL related, make sure you have only one version of it installed and used, sometimes reinstalling it with RVM could help:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it right away. I wonder, since I use macports instead of homebrew. If I install gcc-4.7 from macports, will it work? I'll give it a go.

Comment: There were few reports of broken ruby when used with macports, I do not think it's directly fault of macports but that additional steps are required to make it properly working.

Comment: Hello, I actually removed xCode - that was one big mess on Mountain Lion - macports and re-installed everything. Worked fine now! Also thanks for the the great RVM software! :-) 

ps. Using the pHash gem (creates hashes for media files) fails because of some libffi issue. The lib is installed but some gems are able to find it while others are not. Weird. Octopress seems to work fine however, so thanks!